# Heroku actionmailer how to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am trying to create an email adress. I have added the sendgrid plugin to my app.

Here is my application.rb

```
module Konkurranceportalen
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    #  all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address  => "smtp.mydomain.com",
  :port  => 25,
  :user_name  => "mail@mydomain.com",
  :password  => "mypass",
  :authentication  => :login
}
end
end
```

Comment: What is the question? Does what you have not work? Do you get an error?

Comment: I get an error when I try to login and send an email to mail@mydomain.com in thunderbird

Comment: Should I use sendgrids SMTP server or is it built in Rails?

Comment: Just to be sure: do you want to send an email from your Rails application hosted on Heroku (this is my answer below) or do you want to receive an email in your Rails application?

Comment: I want to send an email from my rails application on Heroku and receive an email in thunderbird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an regular email like mail@yourdomain.com you need an Mail Exhange host.

When you have choicen your mail exhange host you can create emails like mail@yourdomain.com

Now you need to setup the Mx record on you DNS server

And vola you have a email like mail@yourdomain.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your settings for Sendgrid:

```
 ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port           => "25",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => ENV['SENDGRID_DOMAIN']
```

Comment: Do I need to create an sendgrid account?

Comment: How do I create an email adress like mail@mydomain.com

Comment: No, from Heroku you don't. You just need to add Sendgrid to your application with: `heroku addons:add sendgrid:free`

Comment: In addition, Sendgrid statistics (http://github.com/hone/heroku-sendgrid-stats) are really helpful. If you are new to Heroku, you might be interested in the following link, where I put down my own experiences with first-time deploy on Heroku: http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/12

Comment: Sorry for third comment, I just realized your problem. You can't send an email to "mail@mydomain.com". You need to set up a mail server yourself (or use Google Apps with your domain). However, you can't process emails in your application this way. If you need to do that, there is another option: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cloudmailin

Comment: Do you now a good guide how to setup an email in a rails app on heroku? – tzown 5 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

that doesn't look like the code you need to use SendGrid with on Heroku - the docs have all the details you need, [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid)

Comment: How do I create an email adress like mail@mydomain.com

Comment: specify that in your action mailer see http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: to clarify, the code snippet are the settings required to connect your application to SendGrid via SMTP. You then need to use actionmailer to send your email.

Comment: Do you now a good guide how to setup an email in a rails app on heroku?

Comment: The link 2 comments up is a great start!

Comment: I have now setup google Mx Records but I cant send emails to my mail@mydomain.com

Comment: What are you trying to do - in the other answer you said you were trying to send emails from your application to an email account - Is this still the case?

Comment: I am trying to setup an regular email. That I can use to send emails and receive emails. In my app I want to create an contact page that use my email as from email